# iOS Navigation bar smooth transition

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I have an app where the first screen (the menu for the app) does not need a navigation bar BUT the rest of the app does.

The code I am using works fine in the sense that the navigation bar is not present on the menu screen and is present elsewhere in the app BUT the BIG PROBLEM is that once you go back to the menu the navigation bar appears for about a split second and then disappears.

That is NOT a very smooth transition.

How do I make the transition SMOOTHER so that the navigation bar DOESN'T even appear for a second when I go back to the menu screen?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated {
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is related to `xcode`?

Comment: Xcode offers options for dealing with navigation bars under "simulated metrics" that may or may not be helpful here - I did not want to dismiss this as a possible component to the solution.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `xcode` the `xcode` tag is reserved for issues related to the `xcode IDE` itself not issues that your having within `xcode`. So an issue with the `xcode IDE` would be "Why does `xcode` not open?" and "How do I update `xcode`? and questions as such.

Comment: Thx. Do you have any insight into the navigation bar issue here @Popeye ?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it may helps you...

Comment: The above doesn't make a difference. I should have mentioned that I tried "animated: YES" in all 3 areas and no luck. Thanks though Erik.

Answer (score 1):

In your first view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

In your second view controller (not needed, but good practice for code clarity) :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set this in the view did disappear in first screen of the app

```
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

and this in viewdiddisappear of the second VC

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding and showing the navigation bar, you can update the alpha for the navigation bar. It will animate smoothly during the transition. For the view controller with transparent nav bar, instead of modifying the nav bar, create a navbar (or just the back button and title etc.) manually in the second controller's view. We will then hide the navbar when transitioning from first view controller to the second one.

On your second controller's `viewWillDisappear` and on your first view controller's `viewWillAppear:`, set the navigation bar alpha to zero using `self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;`. Since this is in animation block, this will make the navigation bar disappear during the push animation.

Set the alpha back to one in second controller's `viewWillAppear` and first controller `viewWillDisappear`.